# How to Deserialize Parcelled "android.messages" in Android Notification's extras?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-notifications

I am writing my first Android app which includes the `NotificationListenerService` for the purpose of notification mirroring to other devices. I noticed for messaging applications subsequent messages from the same sender post with the same ID/key and only the latest message text appears in the  "android.text" extra field.

My goal is to grab the previous unread messages which look to be attached to the `Notification` under "android.messages" extra. My issue is that this does not read out to a char sequence or string array, instead it looks like some class which implements `Parcellable` is stored here.

I'm hoping there is some standard Android class used here that I'm missing which I can use to deserialize to in order to get the previous messages.

Some code:

```
val pArray: Array<Parcelable>? = bundle.getParcelableArray("android.messages") // Parcelable[6]@17975
println(pArray?.get(0)?.describeContents()) // 1 == CONTENTS_FILE_DESCRIPTOR

val charSequence: Array<CharSequence>? = bundle.getCharSequenceArray("android.messages") // null
val list = bundle.getStringArrayList("android.messages") //  null
val arr = bundle.getStringArray("android.messages") // null
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone stumbles upon this thread, I figured out how to do it:

```
val pArray: Array<Parcelable> = bundle.getParcelableArray("android.messages") as Array<Parcelable>
val messages = Notification.MessagingStyle.Message.getMessagesFromBundleArray(pArray)
```